# How to align the content inside tab

Tags: html, css, tabs, alignment

I'm using semantic tab and cards on my website. I have a list of cards inside a tab. The problem is i can't align those cards to center inside the tab. I tried align center and it doesn't work.i don't want align-text center because i don't want the text to be in the center but the content, although align-text center works. This is more a question of design but still is getting right on my nerves.

UPDATE:

```
<div class="container" style="align:center;padding-top:5%; padding-left:1%;padding-right:1%;padding-bottom:2%">
    <div class="ui top attached tabular menu" >
        <a class="active item" data-tab="first">
            <b><p style="font-size:120%">first</p></b>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="ui bottom attached active tab segment" data-tab="first" style="align:center;padding-top:2%;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="ui cards">   
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img class="ui medium image" height="50%" width="70%" src="/image6.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="header"></div>
                        <div class="description"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="extra content">
                        <a class="right floated created">
                            <div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></div>
                            <div data-toggle="button">                                     
                                <a class="friends">
                                    <i class="user icon"></i>...
                                </a>
                            </div>       
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>    
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is the code except that is not just one card.the tab is filled with information from a database, that is if there is 4 rows on the database there will be 4 cards...i tried the margin-right and left and it worked by it only put one card in each row of the tab

Comment: You need to post some HTML and CSS...

Comment: `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center;` should center any content

Comment: Can you post some example code or something like plunkr that demonstrates the issue specifically?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is cards but I think this is something like div tag ect..

div can be aligned center with the help of margin.

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

If no change,

Add 'display:block' along with this.

But it will not work if you use 'float' or 'display:inline-block' css property with the same div.

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your problem

```
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
width: 50%;
```

or use

```
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
text-align: center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
<div class="tab">
<p>This is text.</p>
<p>This is text.</p>
<span>This is content</span>
<p>This is text.</p>
</div>

.tab {
width:300px;
}
.tab span {
width:100px;
position:absolute;
left:50%;
margin-left:-50px
/*50% of width*/
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/n3vm18be/)